# Failed message in Publish Queue but publishes successfully

Tags: content-delivery, deployer, deployer-extension

We publish some very large pages with videos on them with a custom deployer to Amazon S3.  [The code for the deployer is here.](https://github.com/aeyckerman/tridion-camel-extension)

It takes a few minutes to publish the Page.  During this time the transation is in the 'in progress' (or something similar) folder on the Deployer...

After a while the Publish Queue in the GUI says 'Failed', however, the item is still in progress and it does succeed to get to S3.

Is there a configuration setting in the Transport config or Deployer we can set to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this will be a polling timeout or something, where the publisher (or more accurately, the transport service) has basically given up on the job as a lost cause but the deployer has carried on regardless. You should be able to check by looking at the failure message in more detail.

You can change the polling settings in your

> %TRIDION_HOME%\config\cd_transport_conf.xml

Look for the `<Polling>` element and try increasing the timeout attribute (I believe it's in minutes)

P.S. If it is that, then you might also have a status file sitting at your deployer that will never get picked up and removed... You probably want to clear that up.